# Web Scraping child classes or cleaning up html returned

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get MLB game odds and total runs from rotowire. I have tried two approaches and while I can get close, can't quite figure out what I need to do next. The first approach looks like I need to scrape the child class "composite hide." The other approach I have taken returns a bunch of new line and other extra characters despite my attempt to just get the text and strip those out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

##First approach
oddsData = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'lineup__odds-item'})
print(oddsData)

#Second approach
gameOdds = [g.text.strip() for g in oddsData]
print(gameOdds)
```

The first approach returns the following. I only want the CLE -165 and 7.0 runs.

```
[<div class="lineup__odds-item">
<b>LINE</b> 

                                                <span class="composite hide">CLE -165</span>
<span class="fanduel">–</span>
<span class="draftkings hide">–</span>
<span class="betmgm hide">–</span>
<span class="pointsbet hide">–</span>
</div>, <div class="lineup__odds-item">
<b>O/U</b> 

                                                <span class="composite hide">7.0 Runs</span>
<span class="fanduel">–</span>
<span class="draftkings hide">–</span>
<span class="betmgm hide">–</span>
<span class="pointsbet hide">–</span>
```

The second approach returns the following.

```
['LINE\xa0\r\n                                                CLE -165\n–\n–\n–\n–', 'O/U\xa0\r\n                                                7.0 Runs\n–\n–\n–\n–'
```

Comment: Can I see the output? Like give an example of what's missing and what you want to remove

Comment: @AstronomyComputing I've edited the question to show what is being returned.

Comment: What text you want to find or all of them you want inside that div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `LINE` and `O/U` content you can use this example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for i in soup.select(".lineup__bottom"):
    visit = i.find_previous(class_="lineup__mteam is-visit").get_text(
        strip=True
    )
    home = i.find_previous(class_="lineup__mteam is-home").get_text(strip=True)
    line = i.select_one(
        '.lineup__odds-item b:contains("LINE") ~ span'
    ).text
    ou = i.select_one('.lineup__odds-item b:contains("O/U") ~ span').text

    print(
        "{:<25} {:<25} LINE: {:<10} O/U: {:<10}".format(visit, home, line, ou)
    )
```

Prints:

```
White Sox(33-22)          Indians(30-24)            LINE: CLE -165   O/U: 7.0 Runs  
Twins(22-32)              Orioles(18-37)            LINE: MIN -170   O/U: 9.0 Runs  
Rays(35-21)               Yankees(30-25)            LINE: TB -135    O/U: 7.5 Runs  
Marlins(24-29)            Blue Jays(28-25)          LINE: TOR -160   O/U: 8.5 Runs  
Phillies(26-29)           Reds(24-29)               LINE: –          O/U: 7.5 Runs  
Nationals(22-29)          Braves(25-27)             LINE: ATL -140   O/U: 8.5 Runs  
Tigers(23-32)             Brewers(29-26)            LINE: MIL -180   O/U: 7.5 Runs  
Padres(34-22)             Cubs(31-23)               LINE: CHC -130   O/U: 8.5 Runs  
Pirates(20-34)            Royals(27-26)             LINE: KC -170    O/U: 8.5 Runs  
Red Sox(32-22)            Astros(30-24)             LINE: HOU -165   O/U: 9.0 Runs  
Rangers(22-34)            Rockies(21-34)            LINE: –          O/U: 9.5 Runs  
Mets(26-21)               Diamondbacks(20-36)       LINE: NYM -120   O/U: 9.0 Runs  
Angels(25-30)             Giants(34-21)             LINE: SF -160    O/U: 7.0 Runs  
Athletics(32-25)          Mariners(28-28)           LINE: OAK -160   O/U: 7.5 Runs  
Cardinals(31-24)          Dodgers(32-23)            LINE: LAD -200   O/U: 8.5 Runs
```

Comment: This looks close to working but I get the following error when it gets to scrape the line - NotImplementedError: ':-soup-contains' pseudo-class is not implemented at this time.

Comment: What version of beautiful soup do I need? I just upgraded to 4.9.3 and still received the error. I did switch to contains and it does work though. Do you have any links to more information on this select_one and contains? I have never used this and would like to learn more.

Comment: @ShawnSchreier Depends on the `soupsieve` module `bs4` is using. Here is info about the pseudo-class: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:-soup-contains

Comment: Thanks for your help. Any luck that you could help me get the rain and weather as well. I have tried following your approach which returns an attribute error -- 
rain = i.select_one('.lineup__weather-text b:contains("Rain") ~ span').text 

I've also tried 

forecast = i.select_one('.lineup__weather-text').text.strip() 

This gets me close, but is still including \r\n and a bunch of blank spaces in between each element. If you'd prefer I can post a new question.

Comment: @ShawnSchreier to not clutter the comment section I'd suggest to open a new question. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: I've posted the question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814115/scraping-web-data-using-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to clean up your data follow this general approach:

```
def clean_page(html, pretty_print=False):
    """
    >>> junk = "some random HTML<P> for you to try to parse</p>"
    >>> clean_page(junk)
    '<div><p>some random HTML</p><p> for you to try to parse</p></div>'
    >>> print clean_page(junk, pretty_print=True)
    <div>
    <p>some random HTML</p>
    <p> for you to try to parse</p>
    </div>
    """
    from lxml.html import fromstring
    from lxml.html import tostring
    return tostring(fromstring(html), pretty_print=pretty_print)
```

Here is a detailed article if needed:
https://schoolofdata.org/handbook/recipes/cleaning-data-scraped-from-the-web/?__cf_chl_managed_tk

let me know if this is what you are looking for!!