# Scraping MLB daily lineups from rotowire using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the MLB daily lineup information from here: https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php

I am trying to use python with requests, BeautifulSoup and pandas.

My ultimate goal is to end up with two pandas data frames.

First is a starting pitching data frame:

| date | game_time | pitcher_name | team | lineup_throws |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Spencer Strider | ATL | R |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Zack Wheeler | PHI | R |

Second is a starting batter data frame:

| date | game_time | batter_name | team | pos | batting_order | lineup_bats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Ronald Acuna | ATL | RF | 1 | R |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Ozzie Albies | ATL | 2B | 2 | S |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Austin Riley | ATL | 3B | 3 | R |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Kyle Schwarber | PHI | DH | 1 | L |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Trea Turner | PHI | SS | 2 | R |
| 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Bryce Harper | PHI | 1B | 3 | L |

This would be for all game for a given day.

I've tried adapting this answer to my needs but can't seem to get it to quite work: [Scraping Web data using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67814115/scraping-web-data-using-beautifulsoup)

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code from the link I am trying to adapt, but can't seem to make progress:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

weather = []

for tag in soup.select(".lineup__bottom"):
    header = tag.find_previous(class_="lineup__teams").get_text(
        strip=True, separator=" vs "
    )
    rain = tag.select_one(".lineup__weather-text > b")
    forecast_info = rain.next_sibling.split()
    temp = forecast_info[0]
    wind = forecast_info[2]

    weather.append(
        {"Header": header, "Rain": rain.text.split()[0], "Temp": temp, "Wind": wind}
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(weather)
print(df)
```

The information I want seems to be contained in `lineup__main` and not in `lineup__bottom`.

Comment: Help us to help you - Provide the code you have written and get stuck as [mcve], so that everybody could reproduce your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate the boxes and select all your expected features.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data_pitiching = []
data_batter = []
team_type = ''

for e in soup.select('.lineup__box ul li'):
    if team_type != e.parent.get('class')[-1]:
        order_count = 1
        team_type = e.parent.get('class')[-1]

    if e.get('class') and 'lineup__player-highlight' in e.get('class'):
        data_pitiching.append({
            'date': e.find_previous('main').get('data-gamedate'),
            'game_time': e.find_previous('div', attrs={'class':'lineup__time'}).get_text(strip=True),
            'pitcher_name':e.a.get_text(strip=True),
            'team':e.find_previous('div', attrs={'class':team_type}).next.strip(),
            'lineup_throws':e.span.get_text(strip=True)
        })
    elif e.get('class') and 'lineup__player' in e.get('class'):
        data_batter.append({
            'date': e.find_previous('main').get('data-gamedate'),
            'game_time': e.find_previous('div', attrs={'class':'lineup__time'}).get_text(strip=True),
            'pitcher_name':e.a.get_text(strip=True),
            'team':e.find_previous('div', attrs={'class':team_type}).next.strip(),
            'pos': e.div.get_text(strip=True),
            'batting_order':order_count,
            'lineup_bats':e.span.get_text(strip=True)
        })
        order_count+=1

df_pitching = pd.DataFrame(data_pitiching)
df_batter = pd.DataFrame(data_batter)
```

|  | date | game_time | pitcher_name | team | lineup_throws |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Freddy Peralta | Brewers | R |
| 1 | 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | Jose Quintana | Mets | L |
| .. |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | 2024-03-29 | 10:10 PM ET | Bobby Miller | Dodgers | R |

|  | date | game_time | pitcher_name | team | pos | batting_order | lineup_bats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | J. Chourio | Brewers | RF | 1 | R |
| 1 | 2024-03-29 | 1:40 PM ET | W. Contreras | Brewers | C | 2 | R |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 178 | 2024-03-29 | 10:10 PM ET | E. Hernandez | Dodgers | CF | 8 | R |
| 179 | 2024-03-29 | 10:10 PM ET | Gavin Lux | Dodgers | 2B | 9 | L |